# Why is the force of a magnetic field or a magnetic field not a vector field?

Tags: electromagnetism, vector-fields

I was looking for examples of  conservative and non conservative vector fields and stumbled on the question [Is magnetic force non-conservative?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/118498/is-magnetic-force-non-conservative) and in the  answer section, it is stated the magnetic force cannot be a vector field so it cannot possibly be considered conservative. As I am learning the maths for divergence and curl naturally I wanted to find some examples to help my intuition and that is what leads me to ask for an explanation of the explanation I found on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The magnetic force is not a vector field because vector fields are functions $\mathbf F:\mathbf r \mapsto \mathbf F(\mathbf r)$ that take a single vector value at each position, and the magnetic force $\mathbf F=q\mathbf v\times \mathbf B(\mathbf r)$ also depends on the velocity of the particle that's experiencing the force.

You *could* ask, instead, for the magnetic force *on a particle with a given velocity*, which itself may or may not depend on the position, i.e. $\mathbf v=\mathbf v(\mathbf r)$ (where that dependence may just be a constant), in which case you'll get a map
$$
\mathbf F:\mathbf r\mapsto \mathbf F(\mathbf r)=q\mathbf v(\mathbf r)\times \mathbf B(\mathbf r)
$$
that does have a unique value at each position and which therefore does define a vector field, of which you can ask e.g. whether it's conservative or not. However, until you actually define what velocity dependence $\mathbf v(\mathbf r)$ you want to take, none of those terms are applicable.

Comment: If it's not a function then that would explain it.  I accept the answer . Although not my original question you have peaked my curiosity.  Are you allowed to say a little more as to why the magnetic force also depends on the velocity of the particle that's experiencing the force?   Is q charge times  velocity crossed by a position function? A guess on my part.    Couldn't we say this about any force field and exclude them from being functions or is there something special about the magnetic field ?  vs. say the electric or gravitational field.  Thank you

Comment: @Sedumjoy note that in the examples you mentioned (electric, gravitational), the "force" fields must likewise not be functions as they depend on the electric charge and object mass respectively. Again, _for a given object_, these fields will be fully determined independently of the velocity.

Note however that the underlying _potential_ fields (which in the case of electric and gravitational are scalars, and magnetic, vector) _are_ uniquely functions of position and so therefore are fields proper.

Answer (score 5):

It is indeed a vector field in the sense that it associates a vector to every point in the space, except that the vector is in $T_p^*M\otimes T_pM$ rather than $T_pM$, where commonly used vectors live.

Comment: In that case it would be more accurate to say that magnetic force is a *tensor field*. Saying that it is a vector field *might* technically be correct, but is misleading. Moreover, most of the time a vector field is *defined* to be a section of $TM$, which would actually make that explanation incorrect.

Comment: I feel like you're moving the goalposts, but fine, if you want this to be a old-school vector (section of the tangent bundle) just take the phase space to be the underlying space and it still works.