# Mathematical form of the magnetic force - a vector field or not?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, vectors, definition, vector-fields

*Is the magnetic force a vector or a vector field?*

The magnetic force is written without arguments:
$$
\mathbf F=q \mathbf u \times \mathbf B \tag{1}
$$
Does it mean that $\mathbf r=(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3$: 
$$
\mathbf F(\mathbf r)=q\mathbf u(\mathbf r)\times \mathbf B(\mathbf r). \tag{2}
$$

Or is $\mathbf r$ a function of $t$, $\mathbf r(t)=(x(t),y(t),z(y))$:
$$
\mathbf F(t)=q\mathbf u(\mathbf r(t))\times \mathbf B(\mathbf r(t)), \tag{3}
$$

Or is $\mathbf u$ the derivative of $\mathbf r(t)$, $\mathbf u(t)=\dot{\mathbf r}(t)$:
$$
\mathbf F(t)=q\mathbf u(t)\times \mathbf B(\mathbf r(t))=q\dot{\mathbf r}(t)\times \mathbf B(\mathbf r(t)) \tag{4}
$$

Which one of the last three equations is mathematically correct?

Mathematical detalis:

> In equation $(2)$:
>   Here I consider two vector fields, $\mathbf B:\mathbb R^3\rightarrow \mathbb R^3$ and $\mathbf u:\mathbb R^3\rightarrow \mathbb R^3$. $\mathbf r$ is a constant vector, $\mathbf r\in\mathbb R^3$, i.e. $\mathbf r=(x,y,z)$. If so $\mathbf F$ must also be a vector field, $\mathbf F:\mathbb R^3\rightarrow \mathbb R^3$.
>
> In equation $(3)$: I thought of two vector fields, $\mathbf B:\mathbb R^3\rightarrow \mathbb R^3$ and $\mathbf u:\mathbb R^3\rightarrow \mathbb R^3$. But $\mathbf r$ is a vector function, $\mathbf r:\mathbb R \rightarrow  \mathbb R^3$, i.e. $\mathbf r(t)=(x(t),y(t),z(t))$. 
>   And we parametrize the vector fields with $\mathbf r(t)$, so $\mathbf B(\mathbf r(t))$ and $\mathbf u(\mathbf r(t))$. If so $\mathbf F$ must be a function of one variable, $\mathbf F:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R^3$.
>
> In equation $(4)$: I thought of the vector field $\mathbf B:\mathbb R^3 \rightarrow  \mathbb R^3$, but $\mathbf u$ is not a vector field, just a vector function of one variable, $\mathbf u:\mathbb R \rightarrow  \mathbb R^3$, i.e. $\mathbf u(t)=(x(t),y(t),z(t))$.  Also here we parametrize the vector field, $\mathbf B(\mathbf r(t))$.
>   And from classical mechanics we know that the derivative of the position vector is the velocity vector, so $\dot{\mathbf r}(t)=\mathbf u(t)$. If so $\mathbf F$ must be a function of one variable, $\mathbf F:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R^3$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the force of a magnetic field or a magnetic field not a vector field?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/363394/)

Answer (score 3):

The *standard* understanding of the Lorentz force is as your equation $(4)$: the force is only specified once you know the position $\mathbf r(t)$ of the particle *and* its velocity $\mathbf u(t)=\dot{\mathbf r}(t)$ at that time (though note a probable typo in your notation - $\dot{\mathbf u}$ is the acceleration, not the velocity), as
$$
\mathbf F(t) = q \dot{\mathbf r}(t)\times \mathbf B(\mathbf r(t)).
$$

However, it is *also* possible to consider situations like the force field felt by some extended charge distribution $\rho(\mathbf r,t)$ moving with some velocity field $\mathbf u(\mathbf r,t)$, in which case the total magnetic force on the distribution at time $t$ is given by
$$
\mathbf F(t) = \int \rho(\mathbf r,t) \mathbf u(\mathbf r,t)\times \mathbf B(\mathbf r,t) \, \mathrm d\mathbf r,
$$
which is a close analogue to your equation $(2)$, particularly if you consider the force density acting on each individual chunk $\rho(\mathbf r,t)\,\mathrm d\mathbf r$ of charge.

Your equation $(3)$, on the other hand, makes very little sense - there isn't really a situation where $\mathbf u$ is a function of the trajectory but it isn't simply its derivative.

Comment: Hi! I recently updated the question with more details!

Comment: @Donsert My answer remains unchanged.