# Can non-conservative field store energy when work is done?

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, magnetic-fields, work, conservative-field

Taking a non-conservative field like magnetic field (in presence of current density), when work is done can it store energy? If so how?

Comment: The magnetic field is a conservative field

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/118498/2451 and links therein.