# Does magnetic force being nonconservative heat the object up?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, magnetic-fields

Non conservative forces like friction reduce total energy and it gets dissipated as heat. Does magnetic force being non conservative also produce heat. If not then how is the decrese energy relesaed.

Also, if there is no friction, can heat still be generated(in mechanics, without considering chemical or nuclear reactions)

Comment: Check out the answers to this previous item; they have some good exploration of when the magnetic field is or is not conservative. They can get a little technical, though. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/118498/is-magnetic-force-non-conservative

Answer (score 0):

Magnetic forces alone are not capable of doing work, so they cannot generate heat in an object. To see this, consider the force on a charge $q$ moving with velocity $\mathbf{v}$,
$$\mathbf{F} = q \mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{B}.$$
From the definition of work,
$$W = \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{v} = \left(q \mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{B}\right) \cdot \mathbf{v} = q \left(\mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{v}\right) \cdot \mathbf{B} = 0.$$
Thus, there is no way to extract energy from a static magnetic field and heating is impossible.

However, a *changing* magnetic field induces an electric field by Faraday's Law. In a conductive material this results in oscillating currents, which generate heat. This is how [induction heating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induction_heating) works.