# Lagrangian of Non-Relativistic Charged Particle in a Magnetic Field

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, velocity, potential, classical-electrodynamics

I'm trying to derive the Lagrangian for a non-relativistic charged particle under the influence of a magnetic potential.

I'm assuming that $F=-\textrm{grad}(V)$ and so by the Lorentz force we have $-\textrm{grad}(V)=q v \times (\textrm{curl}(A)) $ and thus I would somehow like to "solve" for $V$ in order to plug it into the Lagrangian $L\equiv T-V$.

However, doing so, I arrive at $-\partial_j V=q\sum_iv_i\left(\partial_j A_i-\partial_i A_j\right)$ and I don't see an obvious way to get from here to $V=-\frac{q}{c}\sum_iA_i v_i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint to the question (v2): For a velocity-dependent force ${\bf F}$ (such as e.g. the [Lorentz force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force#Lorentz_force_and_analytical_mechanics)), the relationship between force ${\bf F}$ and potential $U$ is

$$ {\bf F}~=~\frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial U}{\partial {\bf v}} - \frac{\partial U}{\partial {\bf r}}. $$

See e.g. Goldstein, *Classical Mechanics,* Chapter 1. See also e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/53020/2451) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/77325/2451) Phys.SE posts.