# Physical meaning of magnetic vector potential

Tags: electromagnetism

Can anyone give me an intuition of why the magnetic vector potential $A$ is sometimes interpreted  as the electromagnetic momentum ?

I don't know analytical mechanics, just classical electromagnetism

Comment: *Who* refers to the vector potential as momentum? That's nonsense, AFAIK.

Comment: Yes I'm wrong. It's sometimes interpreted as electromagnetic momentum Edited

Comment: See http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/53020/how-to-interpret-the-magnetic-vector-potential

Comment: I already check that one. The problem is that in the solution they show some things that I don't understand, like "canonical momentum ". I search for a more elementary answer

Comment: You might find this helpful:  *"Potential Momentum, Gauge Theory, and Electromagnetism in Introductory Physics"*  http://arxiv.org/abs/physics/9803023

Comment: @AlfredCentauri  I think it's still to advanced for me

Answer (score 0):

In Lagrangian mechanics, one usually introduces the "generalized momentum" as 
$$
p_{\phi_i}:=\frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi_i}
$$where $L$ is the Lagrangian depending on a bunch of generalized coordinates $\phi_1\dots\phi_n$. If you introduce electromagnetic forces, you can derive, that the Lagrangian in the presence of an electromagnetic field has a form like
$$
L=\frac{m}{2}\left(\vec{p}-\frac{q}{c}\vec{A}\right)^2+q\Phi
$$
where $A$ is your vector potential and $\Phi$ your scalar potential, therefore your generalized momentum will be shifted by $A$, i.e. if you write down the respective Newton equation, instead of $\dot{p}$ you will have this shifted by $A$.

The physical meaning behind this formal stuff is, that the electromagnetic field actually carries a momentum, which can be translated into a mechanical momentum. For example, I remember an experiment, where you put two spherical shells into a magnetic field and then turn the field off, the shells will get an angular momentum (I searched for it, didnt find it yet, will update if found).

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the answer. So that means that the total momentum of any particle interacting with a magnetic field is less  by a factor of $A$. Why is this ? Any intuition , if the particle is on magnetostatic field is different from a changing current in time. Does this affect the energy of the particle  By some other factor of $A$?