# Proton or electron charge in the Weinberg-Salam model?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory

I read Quantum Field Theory, Ryder, second edition. Relation (8.86) brings us the famous result:

$e = g \sin \theta_W$

Here Ryder says tht $e$ is the proton charge. However, according to what I understand from the book, that should be the electron charge (which is negative). This is because in relation (8.85) I read that the lagrangian becomes

$L_i= - g \sin \theta_W (\bar{e}\gamma^\mu e) A_\mu +....$

This QED lagrangian can be found on (7.100) as:

$L_i= - e  \bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu \psi A_\mu +....$

Just below on the page Ryder states that here e<0 is the electron charge, which would also agree with the QED form of the lagrangian in the (+,-,-,-) convention, as presented in 
[Gauge covariant derivative in different books](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/54907/gauge-covariant-derivative-in-different-books).

From these I conclude that in the relation $e = g \sin \theta_W$ above $e$ is the electron charge and not the proton charge as stated by Ryder. Where do I make a mistake?

Comment: You are right. I think it is a typo.

Comment: I doubt that any of the standardized constants $e,g$ etc. is ever meant to be negative. When they talk "charge of the electron", they mean the absolute value - or the positron.