# Embedding diagram in west coast signature

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, conventions, wick-rotation

Assume you have a metric in (+,-,-,-) signature,
$$d s^2=e^{2 \Phi(r)} d t^2-\frac{d r^2}{1-\frac{b(r)}{r}}-r^2 d \Omega^2.$$
To embed it, we take $t=$Constant, $\theta=\pi/2$ slice,
$$d s^2=-\frac{d r^2}{1-\frac{b(r)}{r}}-r^2 d \phi^2.$$
We need to embed it into Euclidean space
$$ds^2=dz^2+dr^2+d\phi^2.$$
For the embedding surface, it becomes
$$d s^2=\left[1+\left(\frac{d z}{d r}\right)^2\right] d r^2+r^2 d \phi^2$$
However, as we use the (+,-,-,-) convention, the metric on the embedding surface would have a different sign compared with our metric.

If I don't want to change the convention, how can I explain this -1 difference? It seems we need to define $r=i r_{Euclidean}$, which is a wired operation.

Comment: Might help to understand the concept of [Wick rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick_rotation).

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/354590/2451