# Lagrangian of Klein Gordon equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, notation, klein-gordon-equation

Consider the following Lagrangian density
$$
\mathcal{L}(\Phi,\partial_\mu\Phi)=-\frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu\Phi\partial^\mu\Phi-\frac{m\Phi^2}{2}.
$$

I want to calculate the equation of motion using the Euler-Lagrange equation to derive the Klein-Gordon equation. The E-L equation states $$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial\Phi}-\partial_\mu\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\,(\partial_\mu\Phi)}=0$$ So, I calculated
 $\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\Phi}=-m^2\Phi$, and for the other term
$$
\partial_\mu\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_\mu\Phi)}=-\frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu\bigg(\frac{\partial}{\partial(\partial_\mu\Phi)}\bigg)\underbrace{(\partial_\nu\Phi g^{\nu\alpha}\partial_\alpha\Phi)}_{\text{New free index, $\nu$}}=-\frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu g^{\nu \alpha}(\delta^{\mu}_\nu\partial_\alpha\Phi+\delta^\mu_\alpha \partial_\nu\Phi=-\frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu(\partial^\mu\Phi+\partial^\mu\Phi)=-\partial_\mu\partial^\mu\Phi.
$$

My question is, is it correct that I have to introduce the free index $\nu$, or are there easier ways to do this?

Comment: It looks ok. Can you confirm the sign of the kinetic term? What metric are you using?

Comment: In your last equation, the last expression follows immediately from the first.

Comment: Probably slightly unconventional, but our professor uses $g=\text{diag}(-,+,+,+)$

Comment: @my2cts what do you mean?

Comment: I mean that you don't need to use the metric tensor.

Comment: That was exactly my question, how can I do it without?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is, is it correct that I have to introduce the free index $\nu$
>   , or are there easier ways to do this?

You didn't introduce a free index $\nu$ as it is contracted with another one. A free index means that the index is not summed over. What you did was introduce a $dummy$ index to sum over.

---

The answer to your question, however, is **no** there is not an easier was to do this. In quantum field theory, this is as easy as it gets. The way to prove the derivative of $(\partial \Phi)^2$ is to do precisely what you did by using the definition $\partial_\mu \Phi \partial_\nu \Phi g^{\mu\nu}$ and then use the product rule.

The resulting Klein Gordon equation should not depend on what convention you use for the metric, as you can just multiply by a minus sign to get the relative minus signs correct.

---

The above, however, may give you the impression that equations of motion will not "look" different in different metrics. But that would be wrong. Maxwells equations are a fine example of this.

$$
\partial_\mu F^{\mu\nu} = j^\nu \qquad (+---)
$$

and

$$
\partial_\mu F^{\mu\nu} = -j^\nu \qquad (-+++). 
$$

The equations *look* different but they are not. Indeed the "extra" minus sign in the latter equation comes from the fact that $A_\mu = (-\Phi, \mathbf{A})$ in the $(-+++)$ convention. So the equations are identical. I think that [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/54909/56599) answer may be of some use.