# Why $-i\hbar\vec\nabla$ for momentum in quantum mechanics, while $m\vec{v}$ in classical mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, mass, momentum

I am a little bit confused when thinking of the momentum representation in QM and CM.

In QM, momentum is represented as $-i\hbar\vec\nabla$,
while in classical, momentum is represented as $m\vec{v}$.

At least, where does the mass $m$ in CM gone when meets QM please?

Once I saw a sentence like "What quantum theory really unites is matter and information" from Prof. Xiao-Gang Wen's PPT file. Though I do not understand this sentence at all for the moment.

Comment: Well the intermediate thought process in developing that momentum operator was the de-broglie relationship, momentum = h/wavelength.  From there the connection becomes obvious.

Comment: Thanks much for letting me know the keyword of "de-broglie relationship" which indeed helps to understand momentum better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$-i ħ \nabla$ is the momentum *operator*.  You have to apply it to a wave function to get the actual momentum.

Consider the plane wave solution to the Schrödinger equation: $\Psi = e^{i \mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{r} - \omega t}$.  Applying the momentum operator gives $-i ħ \mathbf{k} \Psi$.  You can see the eigenvalue has units of momentum. (If you can't see it, note that $\mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{r}$ in the exponent is dimensionless, so clearly $\mathbf{k}$ has units of inverse length.  $ħ$ has units of angular momentum, so $ħ \mathbf{k}$ has units of momentum.)

As far as where the mass of the particle factors in, it's in the Schrödinger equation (and thus related to the wave function): $i ħ  \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \Psi \left(\mathbf{r}, t \right) =\left[-\frac{ħ^2}{2m}\nabla^2 + V \left(\mathbf{r}, t \right)\right]\Psi \left(\mathbf{r}, t \right)$

In particular, the classical relationship between momentum and kinetic energy is $E = \frac{p^2}{2m}$.  (That's the same as your $mv$, for $E = \frac{1}{2}mv^2$.)  Note for the free particle in quantum mechanics, it's the same. $E \Psi = - \frac{ħ^2}{2m}\nabla^2 \Psi = \frac{\left(-iħ\nabla\right)^2}{2m} \Psi = \frac{p^2}{2m} \Psi $

Answer (score 3):

I) On one hand $-i\hbar{\bf\nabla}$ is the Schrödinger (position)
representation of the the canonical/conjugate momentum operator $\hat{\bf p}$
in order to satisfy the [CCR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_commutation_relation)

$$\tag{1}  [x^i, p_j]~=~\hbar {\bf 1}~\delta^i_j. $$

II) On the other hand, $m\hat{\bf v}$ is the kinetic/mechanical momentum operator. (Let us for simplicity imagine a non-relativistic setting.)

III) These two momentum concepts are *not* the same, for instance in the presence of an electromagnetic field, see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/45797/2451) Phys.SE answer.

IV) Let us now assume that we are in a situation where the canonical/conjugate momentum operator $\hat{\bf p}$ and the kinetic/mechanical momentum operator $m\hat{\bf v}$ coincide. Then we may represent the velocity operator as

$$\tag{2} \hat{\bf v}~=~\frac{\hbar}{im}{\bf\nabla}$$

in the Schrödinger (position) representation.