# Why is there an inconsistency between the gauge transformation of the classical canonical momentum and the momentum operator in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, operators, momentum, gauge-invariance

I feel that there is a little inconsistency between the canonical momentum of a 
classical charged
particle in an electromagnetic field and the momentum operator associated to the equivalent quantum system.

Explicitly,
let $\vec{A}$, $\varphi$ be potentials for electric and magnetic fields $\vec{E}$, $\vec{B}$. The Lagrangian that describes the motion of a charged particle (of charge $e$) under these fields is

\begin{equation}
L(x,\dot{x},t) = \frac{1}{2}m\dot{x}^2 -e\varphi + \frac{e}{c}\dot{x}\cdot\vec{A}.
\end{equation}

The canonical momenta associated to $x$ are given by
\begin{equation}
p_i = \frac{\partial L}{\partial{\dot{x}^i}} = m\dot{x}^i +  \frac{e}{c}\vec{A}.
\end{equation}

If we perform a gauge transformation
\begin{align*}
\vec{A}' &= \vec{A} + \nabla\Lambda\\
\varphi' &= \varphi -\frac{1}{c}\frac{\partial\Lambda}{\partial t}, 
\end{align*}
then the canonical momentum transforms as

\begin{equation}
p \mapsto p'= p +\frac{e}{c}\nabla\Lambda.
\end{equation}

However, in the quantum case, the gauge transformation transforms operators by conjugation with the unitary operator $U(\Lambda) = \exp(\frac{ie}{\hslash c} \Lambda)$. Namely, for the momentum operator, we have
\begin{equation}
p \mapsto UpU^{-1} = p + [U,p]U^{-1} = p - \frac{e}{c}\nabla\Lambda.
\end{equation}
Here I used the fact that $[f(x),p]=i\hslash\nabla f$.

Where does this inconsistency come from? I suspect that it has to do with something fundamental about the momentum operator, and how it differs from the classical momentum. Indeed, the canonical momentum depends explicitly on the Lagrangian, so it depends on the dynamics of the problem, but in the quantum case, the momentum operator is just an operator defined on a Hilbert space.

What is the meaning of $p$ and $p'$ in the classical case, and how does it differ from the quantum case?

Comment: There is no inconsistency, it's just that there are a lot of arbitrary sign conventions here and you've chosen them inconsistently. For example, you could just have well have said $U(\Lambda) = \exp(\frac{-ie}{\hbar c} \Lambda)$.

Comment: @knzhou That's not true. If you choose the exponential with the opposite sign, then the gauge-transformed wavefunction does not satisfy the Schrödinger equation with the Hamiltonian with the transformed potentials. The sign inside the exponential follows the sign that you take for the gradient of the gauge function in the vector potential. In fact, if you want the gauge transformed wavefunction to follow the Schrödinger equation with the transformed potentials, you are limited to the form exp(ie/hc Lambda) up to a constant (which disappears in conjugation).

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/45796/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic that answer does not explain the sign difference between the classical and quantum case.

Comment: The point is to interpret the velocity rather than the momentum to transform.

Comment: @Qmechanic Why would we do that? Classically the velocity is gauge-invariant.

Comment: The classical model (that corresponds to the quantum model) is gauge-covariant rather than gauge-invariant.