# Obtaining an expression for the Lorentz Force in the Dirac theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics

We know that $P = p - \frac{e}{c} A$

How can we obtain a expression for the Lorentz force from the equation above using the Dirac Theory??

Could you please explain this to me step by step?

The only idea I have now is:
$i\hbar \frac{dP}{dt} = [P,H]$

Comment: See Landau and Lifshitz, The classical theory of fields, section 17, "Equations of motion of a charge in a field."

Comment: Thanks, but Landau doesn't use the Dirac theory for the demostration

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the Dirac theory"? The canonical momentum is a classical concept, and the Lorentz force can be derived classically. Do you mean the Dirac equation? But the quantum-mechanics tag likely implies you are thinking nonrelativistically. The fact that you write $c$ explicitly stengthens this. So do you mean canonical quantization?

Comment: @MichaelBrown I think the question is clear from the last equation Surreal gave. Given the Dirac equation, can we have an Ehrenfest-like equation giving the classical evolution of a charged particle ? Would we recover only the Lorentz force, or will there be extra terms ? This last question is more mine actually :-)

Comment: @Surreal This question has been already answered multiple times on this website. See *e.g.* http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26845/16689 or http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/45796/16689 for instance. Tell us if the answer given there are sufficient for you or not. They are not *step by step* solutions, but perhaps you can understand by yourself, and then answering your question yourself. Don't forget then to publish your solution here of course :-), it may help other users.

Comment: voting to close as a duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26845/4552

Answer (score 0):

Hint: you may write the Dirac equation

$$(i \hbar \gamma^\mu \partial_\mu  - mc) \psi = 0 $$

with the minimal coupling ansatz

$$\partial_{\mu} \rightarrow \partial_{\mu}+ieA_{\mu}$$

And you may find the following [reference](http://www.southampton.ac.uk/~doug/ft1/ft113.pdf) useful

Comment: I think it's even simpler: replace $H=\gamma_{0}\left(\gamma^{i}P_{i}-m+qA_{0}\right)$ in the Heisenberg equation, and take care of the commutator $\left[\mathbf{P},\mathbf{A}\right]$ which should give the magnetic field (or a quantity proportional to it, depending on the conventions of the magnetic field sign, and $\hbar=1$ you may choose or not).

Comment: I think that the conmutator [Pi,A0] give the electric field, and the conmutator [Pi,Gamma_j·Pj] gives the magnetic field. ¿Am I right? Please check my complete answer